# CPU equation between Amazon's EC2 and Google's GCE

Tags: amazon-ec2, google-compute-engine

Is there a rough-and-ready ratio for converting AWS's EC2 vCPU to Google's GCE vCPU?

For instance, what would be the Google equivalent of an Amazon `c5.4xlarge` with 16 vCPU?  Is this as simple as a 1:1 ratio, and so the equivalent would be Google's `c2-standard-16`?  Or is there some multiplier lurking in the threads . . .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They're exactly the same thing on GCP and AWS for Intel/AMD machines -- a hyperthread, a single hardware thread on a CPU core.

> On Compute Engine, each virtual CPU (vCPU) is implemented as a single hardware hyper-thread on one of the available CPU Platforms.
>
> https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/faq

> Each vCPU is a thread of either an Intel Xeon core or an AMD EPYC core, except for M6g instances, A1 instances, T2 instances, and m3.medium.
>
> Each vCPU on M6g instances is a core of the AWS Graviton2 processor.
>
> Each vCPU on A1 instances is a core of an AWS Graviton Processor.
>
> https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/instance-types/

The Graviton2 processor is an AWS exclusive ARM CPU that is marketed as having lower cost/performance ratio.  Presumably "each vCPU is a core" there because the cores in that chip only actually have one thread each.